# Unable to get Impala JDBC connection with Java 1.8

Tags: spring, jdbc, java-8, impala, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to get the impala jdbc connection in an application deployed on Jboss 6; 
below is the spring bean (ID1) datasource definition for same. I am getting the exception while connecting; please refer to the exception below.

It occurs with Java 1.8 version; if I change it to Java 1.7, it works fine.

The below exception occurs only when the application also tries to connect to Oracle DB using the spring bean (ID2). If Oracle connection ID2 is not used, impala connects successfully.

Can someone please help?

Exception  :

```
==java.lang.NullPointerException
===Stack trace...
java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.copyProperties(Unknown Source)
com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFrom 
DriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFrom 
Driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnect onFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
```

I tried to debug into `AbstractDriver.copyProperties()`, the values in properties are as follows -

```
{user=myuser, password=pwd}
```

beans defined in Spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="ID1" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

<property name="driverClassName" 
value="com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver" />

<property name="url" value="jdbc:impala://impalahost:21050/;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=myrealm;KrbServiceName=impala;KrbHostFQDN=xxx" />

</bean>

<bean id="ID2" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
/>
<property name="url"
value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oraclehost:1523/DB" />
<property name="username" value="myuser" />
<property name="password" value="pwd" />
<property name="connectionProperties">
<props>
<prop key="defaultRowPrefetch">5000</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

your url property should be like `<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL"></property>` not with the double slash

Comment: Tried removing slashes; doesn't help. The issue is even if the application tries to connect to Oracle with a bean reference of ID2; in the exception it refers to the cloudera impala driver - com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.copyProperties(Unknown Source)